# Cast Boolean to Int in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, casting

I'm querying this:

```
SELECT 
active, cast(active as int)
FROM samples
```

the table samples in the column `active` has two rows, `true` and `false`, just to test. And the result is:

```
TRUE    0
FALSE   0
```

While the expected value for `true` I wish to be `1`. I don't understand why the cast is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim's answer is absolutely correct, however for your data you need to convert character case:

```
SELECT 
    active,
    CASE WHEN LOWER(active) = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS active_bool
FROM samples
```

Which gives you this:

```
TRUE    1
false   0
True    1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no boolean type in SQLite.  The closest thing would probably just be using an integer column and storing 0 for false and 1 for true.  However, you could use a `CASE` expression to explicitly map the strings `true` and `false` to 1 and 0 respectively:

```
SELECT 
    active,
    CASE WHEN LOWER(active) = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS active_bool
FROM samples
```

Answer updated to take the case of the `active` column into account per the comment by @vasek in his answer.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also tried that syntax, and it also doesn't work. The result is still the same. Also, active is of type boolean.

Comment: There is no actual boolean data type in SQLite, internally it just stores using an integer with 0 or 1 values.  If my `CASE` expression does not work then your data is not what you described.  Perhaps you have whitespace or padding.

Comment: @donnadulcinea You also have a case sensitivity issue here.